# How to download/store image/file inside Google Cloud Storage bucket by just sending image url using npm GCS client?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

After searching on Google, i find that there is no function into npm GCS client yet. i found that i will achieve it by running one instance which will have one image download service & it will download image at there for temp purpose & upload it to GCS bucket. in this situation , do i have to pay extra four charges like running instance ,downloading image(temp) bandwidth  & also image transfer/storing into GCS bucket. ?

Also find one solutions https://cloudinary.com/documentation/fetch_remote_images
cloudinary is exactly what i am looking it.

i am curious to know that is it possible to achieve same kind of thing using GCS bucket. if yes then please tell how ?

I am looking for ideal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to use using Google Cloud Client Libraries, I uploaded an image from an external URL, using **Node.JS v8.9.4** and **npm version 5.6.0** to my bucket, using this code:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage'),
      request = require('request'),
      bucket = 'BUCKET_NAME',
      filename = 'FILE_NAME',
      url = 'IMAGE_URL',           
      storage = new Storage({
        projectId: 'PROJECT_ID',
        keyFilename: 'auth.json'
      });   

var file = storage.bucket(bucket).file(filename);

request({url: url, encoding: null}, function(err, response, buffer) {

  var stream = file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: response.headers['content-type']
    }
  });

  stream.end(buffer);
});
```

Make sure you set `PROJECT_ID`, `BUCKET_NAME`, `FILE_NAME` and `IMAGE_URL`; as well as having the [Service Account JSON key file](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys) in the local directory.

Contents of package.json:

```
{
 "dependencies": {
  "@google-cloud/storage": "^2.3.3"
 }
}
```

Run the code with `npm start server.js`.

If you wish to get a **Signed URL** for this file, add the following extra code I found in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.3.x/File#getSignedUrl):

```
// These options will allow temporary read access to the file
const options = {
  action: 'read',
  expires: '03-17-2025',
};

storage
  .bucket(bucket)
  .file(filename)
  .getSignedUrl(options)
  .then(results => {
    const signed_url = results[0];

    console.log(`The signed URL for ${filename} is ${signed_url}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

Don't forget to set the expiry date to the actual date of expiry you're interested in, by modifying the value of `expires`.

Comment: It's work. Thank you so much @Maxim.! how to get image access URL in return?

Comment: @Vaghasiyakrunal I suppose you mean the Signed URL. I edited my answer with the new code. The Signed URL part is at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you. It is working. that's what exact solutions i am looking for it. Now i can start using google  client storage instead of  https://cloudinary.com/documentation/fetch_remote_images

Comment: What is the alternative if I do not want users to see I am using Google buckets? Because even with signed urls you can spot I am using google buckets